# Why is my word guess program not outputting characters into the dashes even if the character is in the secret word

Tags: netbeans

So for my computer programming course we were asked to create a basic word guess game and I am wondering why my program is not out putting the characters if they are guessed and are in the secret word. Here's what I have currently:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sW = "";
    int numG = 0;
    String flag = "!";
    String wordSF = "", updatedW = "";
    String charG, wordG = "";

    int num1 = (int) (20 * Math.random() + 1);
    switch (num1) {
        case 1:
        if (num1 == 1) {
            sW = "soup";
        }
        break;
        case 2:
        if (num1 == 2) {
            sW = "money";
        }
        break;
        case 3:
        if (num1 == 3) {
            sW = "brain";
        }

        break;
        case 4:
        if (num1 == 4) {
            sW = "colour";
        }
        break;
        case 5:
        if (num1 == 5) {
            sW = "batman";
        }
        break;
        case 6:
        if (num1 == 6) {
            sW = "design";
        }
        break;
        case 7:
        if (num1 == 7) {
            sW = "media";
        }
        break;
        case 8:
        if (num1 == 8) {
            sW = "computer";
        }
        break;
        case 9:
        if (num1 == 9) {
            sW = "monitor";
        }
        break;
        case 10:
        if (num1 == 10) {
            sW = "password";
        }
        break;
        case 11:
        if (num1 == 11) {
            sW = "textbook";
        }
        break;
        case 12:
        if (num1 == 12) {
            sW = "mountain";
        }
        break;
        case 13:
        if (num1 == 13) {
            sW = "sweater";
        }
        break;
        case 14:
        if (num1 == 14) {
            sW = "darkness";
        }
        break;
        case 15:
        if (num1 == 15) {
            sW = "flood";
        }
        break;
        case 16:
        if (num1 == 16) {
            sW = "plastic";
        }
        break;
        case 17:
        if (num1 == 17) {
            sW = "elephant";
        }
        break;
        case 18:
        if (num1 == 18) {
            sW = "cabinet";
        }
        break;
        case 19:
        if (num1 == 19) {
            sW = "speaker";
        }
        break;
        case 20:
        if (num1 == 20) {
            sW = "electronic";
        }
        break;
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < sW.length(); i++) {
        wordSF += "-";                              
    }
    System.out.println(wordSF + "\n");              
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a letter or ! to guess the word");
        charG = input.nextLine();
        charG = charG.toUpperCase();
        numG++;
        if (sW.contains(charG)) {
            updatedW = wordSF.substring(0, sW.indexOf(charG));
            updatedW += charG;
            updatedW += wordSF.substring(sW.indexOf(charG) + 1, wordSF.length());
            wordSF = updatedW;
        }

        System.out.println(wordSF + "\n");
    } while (!charG.equals(flag) && !wordSF.equals(sW));

    if (charG.equals(flag)) {
        System.out.println("What is your guess? ");
        wordG = input.nextLine();
        wordG = wordG.toUpperCase();
    }
    if (wordG.equals(sW) || wordSF.equals(sW)) {
        System.out.println("You won");
    } else {
        System.out.println("you lost");
    }
    System.out.println("The secret word is " + sW);
    System.out.println("You made " + numG + " guesses.");
// TODO code application logic here
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece of code, you have toUpperCase().  All of your words are in lower case.  An upper case letter will not be found in a lower case word because they are different ASCII values.  If you change it to toLowerCase(), then it will fill.

```
      charG = input.nextLine();
      charG = charG.toLowerCase();
      numG++;
      if (sW.contains(charG)) {
          updatedW = wordSF.substring(0, sW.indexOf(charG));
          updatedW += charG;
          updatedW += wordSF.substring(sW.indexOf(charG) + 1, wordSF.length());
          wordSF = updatedW;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that fixed everything